# How would I evaluate P(AorB) when given P(B|A) and P(A)?

Tags: probability

> I'm given some arbitrary values for P(A) and P(B|A).

I know that $$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$ 
So,
 $$P(A\cap B) = P(B|A)*P(A)$$

I also know that $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$
but now I have two unknowns $P(B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$.

> What steps can I take to either solve for $P(B)$ and apply inclusion exclusion to solve for $P(A \cup B)$ or am I perhaps missing something?

**Edit:** This question was part of a multiple choice (where one answer states the correct answer is not provided). As I mentioned in the comments the question did not state that P(A) and P(B) are independent, else the question could have been furthered using P(AandB) = P(A)*P(B). After, solving for P(B) then P(AorB) can be found.

Comment: You don't have enough information to determine $P(A\cup B).$ Say the experiment is rolling a fair die. Event $A$ is "roll a $1$", event $B_1$ is "roll a $1$ or a $2$", event $B_3$ is "roll a $1$ or $2$ or $3$". Then $P(A)=1/6$ and $P(B_1|A)=P(B_2|A)=1$ but $P(A\cup B_1)\ne P(A\cup B_2).$

Comment: @bof That's what I was thinking glad that's the case (that not enough information was provided)! It was a m/c question and I was trying to figure out if I perhaps missed some detail to come up with another equation or something

Comment: Are A and B independent events?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh no that information was not provided in the question, if they were independent I can further the question using P(AandB)=P(A)*P(B), then I can solve for P(B) from that and then finally solve for P(AorB) from there.

Comment: On the other hand, if you were given $P(A)$ and $P(B|\text{not }A)$, that *would* be enough information.